# nature of output of the addition of white noise with colord noise

Tags: fft, correlation, complex-random-variable, white-noise

I want to know that the addition of a uncorrelated time series `x` with a correlated time series, say `y` generates a time series but is that correlated or uncorrelated output? For example: `x` is White Gaussian noise and `y` is pink noise, then `z = x+y` Looking at the plot which is the output of the noisy time series, it is hard to say whether `z` is correlated or uncorrelated. Is there a rule about the nature of the output?

[image]

Comment: Can you re-consider your question a little? You begin with `x` being a correlated time series and `y` an uncorrelated series, but in the very next sentence, `x` is white Gaussian noise (which most people would regard as an uncorrelated series) and `y` is pink noise (which most people would regard as a correlated series). So, which is which? and what, if any, is the _cross-correlation_ between `x` and `y`?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: sorry for the typo. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are $x$ and $y$ uncorrelated? In this case the autocorrelation function of $x+y$ is just the sum of the autocorrelation functions of $x$ and $y$, which if one of them is not white will lead to its sum also not being white.

In general, for stationary processes you have $\phi_{zz}(\tau) = \phi_{xx}(\tau) + \phi_{yy}(\tau) + \phi_{xy}(\tau) + \phi_{yx}(\tau)$ where $\phi_{xy}(\tau) = \mathbb{E}\{x(t)y(t+\tau)\}$. Moreover, since the process is stationary you also have $\phi_{xy}(\tau) = \phi_{xy}(-\tau) = \phi_{yx}(\tau)$. So in general, the autocorrelation of $z$ depends not only on the autocorrelations of $x$ and $y$ but also their cross correlations.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it does not address completely my problems. One variable has a flat power spectrum and so is white (x r.v ) and the other has a non flat spectrum so is colored, consider say brown color (y r.v). Since `x` is white it is uncorrelated to itself and `y` is correlated to itself (each random number for the red noise is positively correlated to the one preceding it). In general, does the addition of an uncorrelated r.v with a correlated r.v give an output that is correlated or uncorrlelated? i.e., `z=x+y` is `z` correlated/uncorrelated?

Comment: It does answer your question. If your variables are independent, the correlation of the sum is equal to the sum of the correlations. Therefore, if one is not white (your $y$), the sum $x+y$ is also *not* white (i.e., samples are correlated to each other correlated), as I wrote in my second sentence.

Comment: Thank you, now it is clear.

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad it helped.